# Do high rep users need to see 'reputation requirement' messages?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation

Do high rep users really need to see this:

[image]

> Highly active question. You have enough reputation to answer this question. The reputation requirement helps protect this question from spam and non-answer activity.

Why show it? Shouldn't it just be shown to users with low reputation?

It actually takes me a split second to register...that this message is actually nothing of value. It's more of noise to me.

I think most high rep users will read through the list of answers and then make a decision.

It would great if the banner is removed and replaced with a simple fire icon.

Comment: It is meant to discourage users from adding more answers.  Hi-rep users too.

Comment: I know I am more careful if I see a message going "90% of people can't do this. You are privileged, you can do this". I will think twice about doing "this".

Comment: I think high reps will read through the answers and then add an answer.

Comment: I think hiding that information about the state of the question could cause some confusing situations occasionally. For one, if someone wanted to protect a question, they'd have no way to tell whether or not someone else had already done it. (Other than to just try it, obviously. But that's not very user-friendly.)

Comment: @Honey well, I mean I'm obviously anecdotal.... but I wouldn't. What's the downside? If it prevents 10% of high rep answers that could be deleted... I think it's a win. No? I don't see what's bad about it.

Comment: You'll get used to it and stop reading them altogether soon enough. Problem solved...?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I mean why not add every other message there too?

Comment: @honey every other message appears there too (just the content gets more detailed)

Comment: related question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337708/remove-or-make-highly-active-question-post-notice-less-visible-annoying

Comment: Every other message? Messages that were otherwise in yellow boxes are now in these blue boxes, so there's those done. Not sure what other messages you're talking about. In any case, my comment was a bit tongue-in-cheek; by putting these useless messages in the blue boxes, they are training us to ignore them. That might not be their intent, but that's the outcome.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I remember before that questions were marked as protected. I suppose a small icon could fulfill that requirement...

Comment: I definitely agree it could be smaller. That's been my first thought each time I've seen it so far. I just assume I'll get used to it as I have with the various other changes that bothered me at first.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337708/remove-or-make-highly-active-question-post-notice-less-visible-annoying

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yeah, high rep users need to see this.

It isn't of the highest priority, but it contains relevant information to the post that a high reputation user (or any user) will benefit from.

It informs us that the question is protected, generally meaning (not always) that there have been several deleted answers and the post has been relatively reviewed by someone familiar with the technology.

However, I don't think it needs to be quite as prevalent. I know that is the new unified banner for all things status, but it is just in the way here. I like the grey fire icon, the titled "Highly active question", and the blue background; but, the explaining text is useless and the positioning is taking up valuable screen space.

Comment: I'm not a fan of the "highly active" description either honestly, since it may have been highly active at some point but the protected status never goes away unless it's manually removed. Kind of weird to see "highly active" and "active 3 years ago" at the same time.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery - That's true as far as individual activity. When I first saw it I took it to mean active views. Either way, perhaps the phrase could be improved, since protected and highly active don't necessarily need to be coupled.